# Why are folders in Visual Studio not copying on Web App deploy

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a project which is a WebApi which is created in VB.net which which takes Rest Requests and then
makes an Soap Request. Once it has Soap response it then returns it as a Json Doc. I used Visual Ent 2019 to develop the App and when i debug the app on my Workstation it works just fine, Returns Data etc. When i go and deploy it to my IIS 10 folder i am having issues.

a) there is a folder called Certs where i store my PK.12 files to access the remote site. For some reason it does not get created when i build the project. I have also a folder called jsonScgema which as schema files and that gets created and copied just fine

As there is no include but an exclude  i assume its included. Could the file issue be due to the fact i added cert file via Windows explorer and not visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had you included those folders in your project before building it as the image below shows?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around i found out that if the folder does not have a file which has been created / added via visual studio it will not be created on deploy on remote server or file system. in my case i went and selected from the folder menu add existing item and picked my pk12 certificate. Any publish after that had the folder and the pk12 files included.